# MySQL: Delete records whose id is not in the result set of another query

Tags: mysql

This should be a pretty simple thing, but I'm quite new to (My)SQL.

Basically, given a `customers` table with attributes `id, client, etc.`, where the `client` field is not necessarily unique, I want to eliminate rows where the `client` field is a duplicate of a previous value.

The following:

```
 SELECT MIN(id) FROM customers GROUP BY client
```

returns the unique id's of the rows I want. I want everything else out.

I tried

```
 DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers GROUP BY client)
```

to no avail. (`ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause`).

Why doesn't it work and what do I need to do to accomplish my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table that holds the values you want to remove.  Then your delete query could be based on that temporary table.